# Reduction from 3-SAT to MAX 2SAT

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability

For some time I've been trying to understand reduction of 3-SAT to MAX 2-SAT.  I reviewed most of most popular books about computational complexity (Thomas Cormen, Papadimitriou) but I can't find an example, only how to do it theoreticaly and since I'm new to the topic I can't really make much progress. I don't fully understand it.

Thanks in advance for all of the comments trying to help.

Comment: A simple proof can be found in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900591/pdf?md5=3f035a1cdc84866de871f314707d15a9&pid=1-s2.0-0304397576900591-main.pdf) (Theorem 1.1 on page 240) It also shows an explicit construction of the MAX 2-SAT instance from the 3-SAT instance.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you start with a 3-SAT instance with $m$ clauses.  The usual reduction shows that each 3-CNF clause of a 3-SAT instance can be transformed into ten 2-CNF clauses such that if an assignment to the 3-CNF clause satisfies it, then exactly seven of the 2-CNF clauses can be satisfied. If an assignment for the clause does not satisfy it, then exactly  six of the produced 2-CNF clauses can be satisfied.

So after doing the transformation for all $m$ of the 3-CNF clauses the resulting MAX-2-SAT instance can have $7m$ of its clauses satisfied iff the original 3-CNF formula is satisfiable.  Since determining the satisfiability of a 3-CNF formula is NP-hard, MAX-2-SAT must be NP-hard as well.